# Describing all existing elements of a class from another class

Tags: java, class

**What I want to do**
I am a complete beginner in Java, having started yesterday with the basics. I installed Eclipse and I'm trying to make a School Principal menu that can give a list of all students and teachers in the school (and add new ones as well, but that's for later). For now I only want to show the existing students because I haven't created any teachers.

**What I have**
For now I've created my student class: (If you see anything wrong or bad form let me know!)

```
public class Student {

    String name;
    int age;
    String program;

    public Student(String StudentName){
        this.name = StudentName;
    }

    public void PrintInfo(){
        System.out.println(name + " is a " + age +" year old student in " + program);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
    }
}
```

And I have this menu class as well, that calls for student population first:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Menu {

    public static void populate(){
        Student s01 = new Student("David");
        s01.age = 12;
        s01.program = "Elementary School";
        s01.PrintInfo(); //******I would like to remove this part******

        Student s02 = new Student("Alex");
        s02.age = 5;
        s02.program = "Kindergarten";
        s02.PrintInfo(); //******I would like to remove this part******
    }

  public static void main(String[] args) {
      Menu.populate();
    System.out.println("Hello!");
    System.out.println("For a list of students, press 1");
    System.out.println("For a list of teachers, press 2");

    Scanner reader = new Scanner(System.in);  // Reading from System.in
    System.out.println("Enter a number: ");
    int n = reader.nextInt(); // Scans the next token of the input as an int.

    System.out.println("You Entered: " + n);
    if (n==1){
        System.out.println("Here is a list of the students:");

   //******I would like to move the printing here******

    }else if (n==2){
        System.out.println("Here is a list of the teachers:");
    }
  }
}
```

**My Question**
Right now, the output is obviously that the students are printed BEFORE the Menu starts writing. That is because I am printing right in the `populate` void. The problem is that if I switch  `s01.PrintInfo();` to the `main()`, it doesn't recognize `s01`. How can I get the program to recognize it?

**The current and desired outputs**

```
David is a 12 year old student in Elementary School  // I want this //
Alex is a 4 year old student in Kindergarten         //   And this  //
Hello!                                                              //
For a list of students, press 1                                     //
For a list of teachers, press 2                                     //
Enter a number:                                                     //
1                                                                   //
You Entered: 1                                                      //
Here is a list of the students:                                     //
               //here <---------------------------------------------//
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Change your populate method to return a `List` of the students

```
public static List<Student> populate(){
    Student s01 = new Student("David");
    s01.age = 12;
    s01.program = "Elementary School";


    Student s02 = new Student("Alex");
    s02.age = 5;
    s02.program = "Kindergarten";

    List<Student> students = new ArrayList<Student>();
    students.add(s01);
    students.add(s02);
    return students;
}
```

And in your main:

```
if (n==1){
    System.out.println("Here is a list of the students:");

    //******I would like to move the printing here******
    List<Student> students = Menu.populate();
    for(Student student: students) {
        student.PrintInfo();
    }
} else if (n==2){
    System.out.println("Here is a list of the teachers:");
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! I knew the solution was simple!

Answer (score 4):

You may have `populate` return a list of `Student` :

```
   public static List<Student> populate(){

            List<Student> students = new ArrayList<Student>();
            Student s01 = new Student("David");
            s01.age = 12;
            s01.program = "Elementary School";

            students.add(s01);

            Student s02 = new Student("Alex");
            s02.age = 5;
            s02.program = "Kindergarten";

            students.add(s02);

            return students;
        }
```

Then use this list in your `main` method :

```
List<Student> allStudents= Menu.populate();
//.... SNIP
System.out.println("Here is a list of the students:");

for(Student student : allStudents){
 student.PrintInfo();
}
```

Comment: Thanks! I can only accept one answer but have an upvote ;)

Answer (score 3):

Before I start answering just some little hints:

- the `public static void main(String[] args)` is only needed in your main class as this is the entry point to your application
- methods in Java are commonly written lowercase, change `PrintInfo` to `printInfo`

What you want to do is writing the Students to a place where other methods can access them as well, as you're having multiple students I would suggest to use an [ArrayList](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html) as well.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Menu {

    public static List<Student> students = new ArrayList<Student>();

    public static void populate() {
        Student s01 = new Student("David");
        s01.age = 12;
        s01.program = "Elementary School";
        students.add(s01) // Adds student 01 to the list

        Student s02 = new Student("Alex");
        s02.age = 5;
        s02.program = "Kindergarten";
        students.add(s01) // Adds student 02 to the list
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Menu.populate();
        System.out.println("Hello!");
        System.out.println("For a list of students, press 1");
        System.out.println("For a list of teachers, press 2");

        Scanner reader = new Scanner(System.in);  // Reading from System.in
        System.out.println("Enter a number: ");
        int n = reader.nextInt(); // Scans the next token of the input as an int.

        System.out.println("You Entered: " + n);
        if (n==1) {
            System.out.println("Here is a list of the students:");

            for (Student student : students) { // iterate over all the students
                student.printInfo(); // prints the info of every individual student
            }
        } else if (n==2) {
            System.out.println("Here is a list of the teachers:");
        }
    }
}
```

Let me know if you have any additional questions.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. When declaring the ArrayList I get "ArrayList cannot be resolved to a type". Do you have an idea why?

Comment: I guess that you're missing out on imports, I've added the imports to the example. In Eclipse you can also use Shift+Ctrl+O for auto importing.

Comment: OH yes I was. I didn't know some types had to be imported. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 3):

You cannot access `s01` from your `main()` because the scope of the `Student` is limited to the brackets in which it was declared. In this case, your students are only visible inside the `populate()` method.

If you want to access them, you need to:

=> Declare them outside of you populate method. For example:

```
  import java.util.Scanner;  
  public class Menu {

        public static Student s01;
        public static Student S02;

        public static void populate(){
            s01 = new Student("David");
            s01.age = 12;
            s01.program = "Elementary School";
            s01.PrintInfo(); //******I would like to remove this part******

            s02 = new Student("Alex");
            s02.age = 5;
            s02.program = "Kindergarten";
            s02.PrintInfo(); //******I would like to remove this part******
      }

      public static void main(String[] args) {
          Menu.populate();
          // call s01 and s02 in you main method
      }
}
```

=> Make the `populate()` method return a list containing the students your created ( which is the best way, in my opinion ).

Comment: Others have mentioned the list option, which is what I will do. But what about declaring them outside? Would it be just declaring a public Student()? Could you please edit your answer to show me how :D

Comment: see updated answer: now, the scope is the whole Menu class.
The list option is a good option, I would go for it. It's just that I wanted to make sure you pay attention to the notion of scope for the variables in java.